# How stretch out image on the full width for image in R HTML UI element?

Tags: html, css, r

I have R code that generates an HTML page with image elements. The image should fill out 100% width of the column - but it not works.

```
    # Plot 'Bar'
    ...
    tags$tr(tags$td(
      colspan="7", align="center", valign="top", width="100%",
      gt::html(gt::ggplot_image(g_bar, height = 200, aspect_ratio = 1.5)))
    ),
    ...
```

Any ideas on how to stretch our "g_bar" on the whole column width?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not fully able to decipher your code, but what I spot is that g_bar is restricted to a specific height and aspect ratio. Obviously, the width is dependent on the height here (via the aspect ratio). I would assume you can increase the height (or use width instead of height),. Also give a shot at removing height/width completely, but I am not sure if this will do a use-full-width by default. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. The width parameter is absent here